# How to create algorithm for ordering posts in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, query

I have a news feed in my website where all the blog posts are displayed. Wordpress default is to dislay these in order "latest first". Using Elementor and Likebtn I have learned how to order the posts based on likes by creating a query ID "sort_by_likes" in Elementor Post Widget and inputting the code below in my functions.php file. But I want to use a more advanced algorithm for displaying my posts which weights in number of views, likes, date of publication and some randomization variable. How can I solve that?

```
add_action('elementor/query/sort_by_likes', function($query){
    
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('meta_key', 'likes');   
});
```

Comment: What's the algorithm? It's impossible to say how to do it without knowing what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderby = array( 
               'likes'      => 'DESC', 
               'views' => 'DESC',
               'date' => 'DESC',
); 


$query->set('orderby', $orderby);
```

Note: Make sure `meta_key` match with your meta keys.

Here is the reference: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/